# Component data not changing after update vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, components, vuex

Hi I have this scenario which every time I update a user it doesn't update my data back from my user component.

what’s happening now is after i update the user.
the correct value is showing then after a millisecond the old value is coming back.

When I console.log the this.$store.state.users;  it return to logs the first is the updated list second is the old list.

here's my store.js

```js
state: {
    users:[],
},
actions:{
    LOAD_USERS({ commit }){
        axios
            .get('api')
            .then(res => {
                if(res.data.success && res.status === 200){
                    commit('SET_USERS', res.data.results.users)
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
    }
},
mutations:{
    SET_USERS(state, users){
        state.users = users
    }
}
```

this is my user. js

```js
mounted(){
    this.$store.dispatch('LOAD_USERS'); 
},

computed: {
    users(){
        return this.$store.state.users;
    },
    filterUsers: function(){    //variable that bind on the table
        if(this.search != null){
            return this.users.filter((user) => {
                return user.full_name.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase())
            });
        } else {
                return this.$store.state.users;     
        }
    }
},
```

and this is my updateuser.js 
where updating is happening.

```js
created(){
    this.user = this.$store.state.userDetails
    this.roles = this.user.role.split(",");
},

methods: {
    getValidationClass: function (fieldName) {
        const field = this.$v.user[fieldName]
        if (field) {
          return { 'md-invalid': field.$invalid && field.$dirty }
        }
    },

    updateUser: function (user, roles) {
        this.$v.$touch()

        if (!this.$v.$invalid) {
            this.$http.post('api'+user.user_id, {
                first_name: user.first_name,  
                last_name: user.last_name,  
                mobile_number: user.mobile_number,
                full_name: user.first_name + " " + user.last_name,
            });

            this.$http.post('api'+user.user_id, {
                role: roles
            });
            this.$router.push('/user') 
        }
    },
},
```

after i push the router back to my users component my data doens't change.
any suggestions on how to make it updated?

Comment: What are you using for `this.$http`? Also, have you checked your console to make sure it's going to the correct endpoint and it not failing?

Comment: Hi @RossWilson it axios actually is just assign it to this.$http. and yes it's going to right end point.. when i refresh the page manually the updates effect.

Comment: Are you using `keep-alive`? Also, do you have Vue Devtools?

Comment: Yes I do have Vue Devtools, about the keep-alive I am not using it. Can you tell me where to put this keep-alive. I'm just familiar but I don't really know how to use it for vuex..

Comment: Keep-alive might have been a reason that it's not updating, however, if you've not implemented it then it probably not the case. Can you also confirm that `this.$store.dispatch('LOAD_USERS');` definitely gets called run after you've navigated back to the `/users` page?

Comment: actually its not firing when navigating from updateUser component to user component.. when the first reload its calling the api. but navigating from component to component i can't see a call from my console.